# Cuenta regresiva no funciona con 2 o mas registros, solo con uno

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo un cuenta atras generado en javascript y se muestra en datatables. El tema es que funciona solo cuando es un registro por linea, pero cuando son 2 o mas, simplemente no muestra el cuenta atras. La consola no muestra errores de ningun tipo. Los registros provenientes de la BD estan correctos y no hay problema con ellos. 
 la funcion que genera el cuenta atras es la siguiente:

```
function faltan() {

    var actualiza = 1000;
    var ahora = new Date();
    var faltan = futuro - ahora;

    if (faltan > 0) {
        var segundos = Math.round(faltan / 1000);
        var minutos = Math.floor(segundos / 60);
        var segundos_s = segundos % 60;
        var horas = Math.floor(minutos / 60);
        var minutos_s = minutos % 60;
        var dias = Math.floor(horas / 24);
        var horas_s = horas % 24;

        (segundos_s < 10) ? segundos_s = "0" + segundos_s : segundos_s = segundos_s;
        (minutos_s < 10) ? minutos_s = "0" + minutos_s : minutos_s = minutos_s;
        (horas_s < 10) ? horas_s = "0" + horas_s : horas_s = horas_s;
        (dias < 10) ? dias = "0" + dias : dias = dias;
        var resultado = dias+ ":" + horas_s + ":" + minutos_s + ":" + segundos_s;
        document.getElementById("text").value = resultado;
        setTimeout("faltan()", actualiza);
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("text").value = "Tiempo Expirado";
    }
}
```

la tabla generada por datatables es la siguiente:

```
{
 "sClass": "alignRight",
 "data" : null,
 'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
          var tiempo = row['tiempo'];
          var splitDate= tiempo.split(" ");
          var date=splitDate[0].split("-");
          var time=splitDate[1].split(":");

          var dd=date[2];
          var mm=date[1]-1;
          var yyyy =date[0];
          var hh=time[0];
          var min=time[1];
          var ss=time[2];

          window.futuro = new Date(yyyy, mm, dd, hh, min);
          return '<input id="text" readonly cols="8" style="resize:none">';
        }
    }
```

Cabe señalar que la variable futuro, es una variable global.
Dejo una imagen como referencia del problema.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientacion al respecto.
Saludos a todos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El id es el mismo para todos los inputs donde añades la cuenta atrás, necesitas que sea diferente y único para cada cuenta atrás. Si la cuenta atrás es la misma en todas las filas, rellena el campo utilizando una clase común en lugar del id.

Comment: los datos son dinamicos, no puedo establecer un id para cada cuenta atras ya que pueden ser 1 a n.

Comment: Le puedes dar el valor de id dinámicamente cuando lo creas, por ejemplo var id="text"+n; donde n es único, por ejemplo un id de la tupla o el número de tupla que estas rellenando. Y a la función faltan le pasas como parámetro el id del campo al rellenar cuando la lances.

Comment: gracias por la informacion. podrias darme un ej de como hacer lo que comentas? debo generar var id como global?  como la usaria en el input? muchas gracias